# Cannot find name '__DEV__'

Tags: typescript, mobx

I have installed mobx library with npm. now when I enter the mobx/src/error.ts file in node_modules folder, I see that there is a compile time error in the 78th line. the line is:

```
const errors: typeof niceErrors = __DEV__ ? niceErrors : ({} as any)
```

and the error is :

Cannot find name '**DEV**'.

in my machine typescript version is "typescript": "^4.3.5"2

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail? When does this problem occur? What do you do before it fails? What is the command you execute?

Comment: I just download mobx library from npm and examine node_modules/mobx/src/error.ts file by visual studio code. and I found that there is a variable in node_modules/mobx/src/error.ts file called __DEV__  which is not declared. because of that, visual studio code gives compile time error : Cannot find name '__DEV__'.

Comment: Can you please try to reproduce this, e.g. via https://stackblitz.com/
That will help a lot to better understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

inside my src folder I created a @types folder then inside that I created a globals folder then a index.d.ts file inside that folder.

inside the index.d.ts file, I wrote

```
export {}
declare global {
declare const __DEV__: boolean;
}
```

which worked for me